# Pulumi: Missing PrimaryAccessKey for EventGrid Topic

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, pulumi

I'm using Pulumi 1.16 with dotnet/C# and the **AzureNative** stack. I try to create an *EventGridTopic*. To access the created resource's properties later I pull some output values.

Example code:

```
      var topic = new Topic("eventgrid-topic-status", new TopicArgs
      {
        TopicName = "egt-status-dev",
        ResourceGroupName = "rg-testapp-dev",
        Location = "westeurope"
      });
      var endPointOutput = topic.Endpoint;
      var endPointAccessKey = ""; // missing output property
```

The resource is being created. I found no way to get the access key properties:

- PrimaryAccessKey
- SecondaryAccessKey

In the former (elder) Azure stack the properties exist. But in Azure Native stack not. Is that on purpose, just work in progress, has been forgotten or is there some other way to retrieve these properties on this object?

This is output on Azure (old stack):

[image: EventgridTopic Output (old stack)]

This is Azure Native, clearly the keys are missing:

[image]

I doubt that this happens accidentally and would like to understand what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure API (and therefore Azure Native resources) return no sensitive information in their outputs automatically to minimize security risks. You have to make an explicit call to retrieve those.

In this case, you likely need to invoke the function [listTopicSharedAccessKeys](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-native/eventgrid/listtopicsharedaccesskeys/).

You will want to call the function from within an `Apply` to make sure that it's triggered only after the topic is created (e.g., not during preview):

```
var keys = topic.Name.Apply(topicName => ListTopicSharedAccessKeys.InvokeAsync(
    new ListTopicSharedAccessKeysArgs
    {
        ResourceGroupName = "rg-testapp-dev",
        TopicName = topicName
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hardcode the resource group name:

```
let keys = pulumi.all([rg.name, topic.name]).apply(arr => 
    azn.eventgrid.listTopicSharedAccessKeys(
        {
            resourceGroupName: arr[0],
            topicName: arr[1]
        }
    )
);

keys.apply(x => pulumi.log.info(x.key1 ?? ""));
```